# Privacy settings when creating a live video object with Facebook Live API

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, live-streaming

I am trying to set privacy settings when creating a live video object with the Facebook Live API via NodeJS. The Go Live dialog in the API docs only covers the client side version of this in detail, not the server side implementation. Everything works the way I would expect it to and the video is posted to my timeline, but the privacy settings on each post are  defaulting to "Only Me".

Here is an example of the object I am POSTing to the /user_id/live_videos endpoint:

```
var options = {
  json: true, 
  headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.accessToken }, 
  data: {
    description: description,
    title: title,
    privacy: {
            "value": "EVERYONE"
    }
  }
}
```

Am I missing something in the privacy object or using it inappropriately? Any suggestions would be helpful. Also, just something to note, I have noticed that since my Facebook App is still in development mode, only users that I have added as testers inside of the app settings can view my live streams. Could this also be affecting the privacy settings that my posts are defaulting to? Thanks in advance!

Comment: is there any solution of this, please provide it?

Answer (score 1):

It could be because when authorising the app, you set *app* privacy to the secure level. App can not create posts with less privacy.
From FO docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/common-scenarios#privacy-param):

> This field cannot be used to set a more open privacy setting than the one granted during login.

So you can revoke access and then authorise through it one more time, selecting "Everyone" in field "Who can see posts made by this app" (or smth similar)

Answer (score -2):

You need to complete your app review for some permission like `manage_pages`, `publish_video`, then you can use this request body parameter for public privacy of timeline live broadcasting.

```
let options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/' + {userId} + '/live_videos',
        qs: { access_token: data.access_token },
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "description": data.description,
            "privacy": {
                "value": "EVERYONE"
            },
            "title": data.title,
            "published": true
        })
    };
```